# How to get specific string within a value of String in List in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a List like this:

```
data_list = ['12 guests · 6 bedrooms · 10 beds · 3 baths', '10 guests · 5 bedrooms · 7 beds · 4 baths',
'13 guests · 6 bedrooms · 8 beds · 4 baths', '3 guests · 2 bedrooms · 2 beds · 2 baths']
```

I want to list like that:

```
data_list = ['6 bedrooms', '5 bedrooms', '6 bedrooms', '2 bedrooms']
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split each list in data list by `' . '` and if it contains the word bedrooms append it to `br_arr`

```
br_arr = []
for data in data_list:
    for ele in data.split(' · '):
        if 'bedrooms' in ele:
            br_arr.append(ele)
```

One-liner using list comprehension

`[ele for data in data_list for ele in data.split(' · ') if 'bedrooms' in ele ]`
Output:

```
['6 bedrooms', '5 bedrooms', '6 bedrooms', '2 bedrooms']
```